# Question about short-cut

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about short-cut here? Is it related to user interface?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney: I want to know that short-cut related question is accepted in this site or not.

Comment: Yes. Post your question here and we'll tell you if we think it's on topic.

Comment: Questions like: How to make shortcuts of elements(like text-box, list etc.) of my web page? Is this question is on or off topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's off topic for this site.  You should try doctype.com or stackoverflow.com

A question like "Should a keyboard shortcut for find be ctrl+f, alt+f, or something else?" would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks